# Query on "text" field in MySQL not working

Tags: mysql, text, varchar

I have a `MySQL` Query that looks something like this,

```
SELECT dactivityid, saction, resolution FROM supactiv where resolution <> ''
```

Now this returns results where `resolution` still has `''` values in it.
My aim is to only show results, which actually have a valid `resolution` value and so are not `''`.
Resolution is a `"text"` field in `MySQL`. Is there any way to fix this query so that it respects the condition in the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created below table and inserted below records and it worked perfectly.

```
------------------------------------------

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `supactiv` 
(

    `dactivityid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,

    `saction` enum('A','B','C','D') NOT NULL,

    `resolution` text NOT NULL,

    `createdon` date NOT NULL,

    `updatedon` timestamp NOT NULL ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

     PRIMARY KEY (`dactivityid`)

) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


------------------------------------------

INSERT INTO `supactiv` (`dactivityid`, `saction`, `resolution`, `createdon`, `updatedon`)

VALUES (1, 'A', '', '2015-07-02', '2015-07-02 17:51:03'),

(2, 'B', 'test', '2015-07-02', '2015-07-02 17:51:03'),

(3, 'C', '', '2015-07-02', '2015-07-02 17:51:03');

------------------------------------------
```

I have created the above table and tried your query it's working absolutely fine. You can check your table type and other aspects.

Or create table SQL and data SQL so I can check and answer you best of mine.

Thank you

Comment: Thanks for this, I have tried your statement and query, which also works fine for me. However, I have just copied the "Create" statement on my "supactiv" table to the clipboard in MySQL workbench and found that the line for creating the "resolution" field does not have "NOT NULL" at the end of it. It looks like this, "`RESOLUTION` text,". Could this be the problem perhaps? It seems that when this table was created, "NOT NULL" was not used.

Comment: I have tried it with both, NOT NULL checked and Unchecked. Both are working fine for me, there might be some white space or special characters. Let me know if you still face problem or give me your export query so I can figure it out.

Comment: Need one favor if it works for you, Please marked as the approved answer.